# IOKit/usb/IOUSBDevice driver not working on macOS 10.13.2

Tags: macos, usb, device-driver, macos-high-sierra, iokit

I have build USB driver using macOS 10.10 and it was working fine on it, able to detect my USB device on 10.10

The same driver is not working on macOS 10.13.2, my USB device is not detecting, below are the logs from console:

```
default 13:13:24.124871 +0800   icdd    #ICDebug - 23:{ICWiredBrowser.m} (USB Device first match)
default 13:13:24.125840 +0800   icdd    #ICDebug - 388:{ICWiredBrowser.m} (13 USB Descriptions Managed)
default 13:13:24.127423 +0800   icdd    #ICDebug - 457:{ICDDMessageCenter.m} (+Add M-WiMAX Network Adaptor - 0x0/0x0/0x0 - 0x14200000 - ICDeviceDescriptionSUQuery)
default 13:13:24.150725 +0800   icdd    #ICDebug - 37:{ICWiredBrowser.m} (USB Interface first match)
default 13:13:24.151923 +0800   icdd    #ICDebug - 388:{ICWiredBrowser.m} (14 USB Descriptions Managed)
default 13:13:24.153475 +0800   icdd    #ICDebug - 457:{ICDDMessageCenter.m} (+Add M-WiMAX Network Adaptor - 0x8/0x6/0x50 - 0x14200000 - ICDeviceDescriptionSUQuery)
default 13:13:24.153499 +0800   icdd    #ICDebug - 205:{ICResourceManager.m} (00000000-0000-0000-0000-000010767F40|M-WiMAX Network Adaptor|(null)|SW=FALSE|)
default 13:13:24.155336 +0800   icdd    #ICDebug - 457:{ICDDMessageCenter.m} (+Add M-WiMAX Network Adaptor - 0x8/0x6/0x50 - 0x14200000 - ICDeviceDescriptionAdded)
default 13:13:24.223748 +0800   icdd    #ICDebug - 205:{ICResourceManager.m} (00000000-0000-0000-3732-303530323033|M-WiMAX Network Adaptor|MANUFACTURER:GCT Semiconductor, Inc.;MODEL:M-WiMAX Network Adaptor|SW=FALSE|)
default 13:13:24.224364 +0800   icdd    #ICDebug - 457:{ICDDMessageCenter.m} (+Add M-WiMAX Network Adaptor - 0x0/0x0/0x0 - 0x14200000 - ICDeviceDescriptionInferior)
default 13:13:24.145800 +0800   kernel  USBMSC Identifier (non-unique): 0x00000000 0x1076 0x7f40 0x2, 2
default 13:13:24.148742 +0800   kernel  USB CD-ROM: family specific matching fails
```

To solve the problem tried to build the same source code on macOS 10.13.3 but received .h files not found error:

> "IOKit/usb/IOUSBBus.h" not found

Below are the files include to my source

```
include "IOKit/IOLib.h"
include "IOKit/IOMessage.h"
include "IOKit/usb/IOUSBBus.h"
include "IOKit/usb/IOUSBNub.h"
include "IOKit/usb/IOUSBDevice.h"
include "IOKit/usb/IOUSBPipe.h"
include "IOKit/usb/USB.h"
include "IOKit/usb/IOUSBInterface.h"
include "IOKit/IOInterruptEventSource.h"
include "IOKit/IOTimerEventSource.h"
```

please help how to make use of old USB driver on macOS 10.13.2